# Java - Print last digit of a number as well as the digit before

Tags: java, for-loop, return, division, modulus

If I want to print the last digit of a number (say 16), I use: number % 10 and the output is 6. If I want to print the digit before the last, I may divide the number by 10 and cast to int. This only applies for numbers! If I want to obtain the digit preceding 6, I would definitely obtain 0, but the challenge is to obtain the same digit and not 0. How is that?

Comment: And what about using `% 100` instead?

Comment: What is the type of your Number? I think the proper way is not to work on the number directly but on the `String` representation of it.

Comment: If it isn't a number then what is it?

Comment: If I used %100 I would obtain the last two digits. However, I am looking for the algorithm that prints the digits preceding the last digit of a number. If that number was a digit, then it'll print 0 and not the same digit.

Comment: Please provide sample inputs and expected outputs

Comment: Your question is pretty **impossible to decrypt**: 1. "I may divide the number by 10 and cast to int" - Well, it's already an `int` according to the fact that you're using `%` on it. So, all you need is to do is divide it by 10 and use `%10` on the result. 2. "This only applies for numbers" - Are we talking about anything else besides numbers here? If yes, then there is no trace of that fact within your question. 3. "If I want to obtain the digit preceding 6, I would definitely obtain 0"... What on earth are you trying to say here?????

Comment: I don't understand what you need to do here so much but why won't you cast the number to string and just use substring like String.value of(the number).substring(lengthOfString - 3, lengthOfString)?

Comment: Example: Print the last digit of 22.
Output: 2.

Example: Print the last digit of 5.
Output: 0.
Question: In such case, I need the output to be 5 (the same number) and not 0.

Answer (score 2):

A simple implementation could look like this:

```
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import static java.lang.Math.max;
import static java.lang.Math.min;

public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(getNthNumber(-16, -14)); // 1
   System.out.println(getNthNumber(16, -14)); // 1
   System.out.println(getNthNumber(16, 0)); // 1
   System.out.println(getNthNumber(16, 1)); // 6
   System.out.println(getNthNumber(16, 4)); // 6
   System.out.println(getNthNumber(12345678, 4)); // 5
}

static int getNthNumber(final int pNumber, final int pIndex) {
   final String numberString = Integer.toString(abs(pNumber));
   return numberString.charAt(max(0, min(pIndex, numberString.length() - 1))) - '0';
}
```

Comment: This is an overkill, IMHO.

Comment: But it's working :-) and for big numbers as well

Comment: Yes, that is true. PS: I edited your answer in order to eliminate the unneeded cast to a String and parse to an integer back.

Comment: Thx ;-) And I added the check for IndexOutOfBoundExceptions and some examples

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think that you are confused by something. This is the straight-forward mathematical way:

```
int i = 16;
int lastDigit = i % 10;
int precedingDigit = (i / 10) % 10;
```

In Java, when you do integer division, the result is always rounded towards zero.

---

For the example you provided, in case of 5. Where you wanted to get the same digit twice:

```
int i = 5;
int lastDigit = i % 10;
int precedingDigit = (i == lastDigit) ? lastDigit : ((i / 10) % 10);
```

Comment: It works. However, I'm still a beginner in Java. I didn't understand the last line of your code Martijn Courteaux.

Comment: That's a _Ternary Operator_ and basically boils down to some kind of `if ... then ... else` and returns the appropiate value.

Comment: What I don't like about the solution above (but that may seen ideomatic) is that it's using _math_ to decide the question about a _digit_. I consider _digits_ to belong to the realm of the _textual representation_ of a number, not the number itself. Expressions used like _before_ also point out that way. Using the `Modulo` operator is on the _math_ realm and only works as long as you know the _base_ of the used represantion. Consider this nit-picking, but I would go for the `String` approach.

Comment: tilois, you have accurately explained to all programmers of Stack Overflow my whole problem. Thank you :)